# Can I create global array in angular 6 which I will modify according to form result?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a form in every tab. How to assign update value to global array so i can use in every file? all values should be updated according to form.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Can i Create global array in angular 6 which i will modify according to form result ..?

Yes, we can update form values by storing them in a Global Variable.

Create a Global Class in your shared module like this

```
@Injectable()
export class Global {

public static formValues = new Map();

}
```

then add your values to Global variable in Components

**childComponent.ts**

```
   Global.formValues.set("mapType", "Hide");
```

you can them with the key

```
    var mapType;
    mapType= Global.formValues.get("mapType");
```

Comment: OK i will try this Solution and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You said that your form is in every tab. So you should create a separate component for your form, add a service file to component and declare your array in service and use from there.

Comment: Yes I tried with same but when i click on any new tab it reset array... i want array value will be remain same as updated form..

Like my main component is 
Editor
Sub Component is Sidebar
in Sidebar component have all tab components.. components load upon click on tab.. there is issue when i click on new tab it reset recent updations... sorry for my English

Comment: Variables inside components are destroyed and created again, but service and variables inside service remain there. If your variable is inside component then you will have to move it to service, and if the variable is in service then you are reseting it, btw if variable is in service then please create a stackblitz and I will help you.